# How do I link to a server generated CSS file with a query string?

Tags: php, html, css, cfml

I want to do this:

```
<link href="/style-render?s=base" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and when I visit `/style-render?s=base`, it gives me the CSS that I want, but the styles are not being pulled into the page.

It works for google:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

So I know it's possible I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does the browser request the resource (check using FireBug or similar tools)?
Does it return the desired CSS?
Also, are you sure that your resource 'style-render' returns the proper Content-Type for the generated CSS?
Your browser's development mode will help you!

Comment: Thanks @JesperSM! i didn't have a content-type declared in the style-render file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out.

So since I was using CFML I had to specify the content-type by using a `cfcontent` tag like so:

```
<cfcontent type="text/css; charset=utf-8">
```

in php you would do it like this:

```
<?php
   header( 'Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8' );
?>
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `content-type` header.  Odds are it's rendering as `plain/text` instead of `text/css`.

In PHP you'd set your header with:

`header('Content-Type: text/css');`